# Which collection type should I use for best performance?

Tags: c#, wcf, performance

While setting WCF client service configuration, there is an option "collection type" which defaults to "System.Array". If I change it to "Generic List", is there any performance loss?

Comment: try                              it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Over the wire (WCF) there is no difference; the same data will be sent.

At the client, there is very little noticeable performance between `List<T>` and `T[]` in most scenarios. Use `List<T>` - it is much easier to get it right (adding etc). If you are doing lots of data-binding, `BindingList<T>` might be useful, but you might want to restrict that to a view-model, not a business object. That *does* have extra cost (with the events etc).

---

Edit: the biggest "performance cost" will be the time you spend fighting it to add items to arrays (with resize, and the cost there-of); so jump to `List<T>` and smile ;-p

Comment: List is basically Array with some management methods taking care of resizing it. That is the overhead.

Comment: But this "overhead" can also be a blessing if you are sequentially adding items, since it leaves spare capacity by default (doubling).